# mostrar informacion de acuerdo a un usuario, sucursal y fecha en Node.js, Express, Handlebars y mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

Estoy empezando en todo esto de Node.js y de mas tecnologías que mencione, estoy tratando de desarrollar una aplicación web administrativa en la cual necesito almacenar información de cada sucursal ya tengo la db en mongodb y ya realice los routers y autentificaciones con passport, **el problema que tengo es que en una vista estoy enviando información capturada con un formulario y en la misma vista la estoy mostrando, solo que no se como mostrar la información de acuerdo al usuario, sucursal y fecha**, de esta información genero la vista en una tipo tabla y cada columna representa un vendedor, **el problema también que tengo es que al enviar la información se actualiza la pagina y no se como hacer para que la fecha se quede con la que selecciono el usuario ya que toda la información que agregan es de un día antes**.
este es aprox mi  .HBS

```
<form action="/cortes/" method="POST" class="form-cortes">
   <input type="date" id="fechacorte">
   <select name="vendedor">
      <option value="v1">Vendedor1</option>
      <option value="v2">Vendedor2</option>
      <option value="v3">Vendedor3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="number" name="ventatotal" />
   <input type="number" name="efectivo" />
   <input type="number" name="vaucher" />
   <input type="number" name="sumatotal" /><!-- es la suma de efectivo y vaucher-->
   <input type="number" name="diferencia" /><!-- si hay sobrante, faltante o 0-->
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
{{#if cortes}}
    <div class="columna">
        <div class="celda"><p>Concepto</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>Valor Corte</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>Efectivo</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>Vaucher</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>Suma Valores</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>Diferencia</p></div>
    </div>
    {{#each corte}}<!-- aqui lo recorro la informacion de cada vendedor que ingrese pero solo ocupo que se vean las que se estan ingresando con la fecha seleccionada-->
        <div class="columna">
            <div class="celda"><p>{{vendedor}}</p></div>
            <div class="celda"><input type="number" class="valorcorte" value="{{valorcorte}}"></div>
            <div class="celda"><input type="number" class="valorcorte" value="{{efectivo}}"></div>
            <div class="celda"><input type="number" class="valorcorte" value="{{vaucher}}"></div>
            <div class="celda"><input type="number" class="valorcorte" value="{{sumavalores}}"></div>
            <div class="celda"><input type="number" class="valorcorte" value="{{Diferencia}}"></div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
    <div class="columna">
        <div class="celda"><p>Totales</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>valor de la suma</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>valor de la suma</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>valor de la suma</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>valor de la suma</p></div>
        <div class="celda"><p>valor de la suma</p></div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

mi archivo de router es algo asi

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Corte = require('../models/Cortes');

router.get('/cortes/', async (req, res) => {
    /*aqui ya hice el primer filtro pero no se como hacer el filtro con sucursal 
    y la fecha, que la fecha seria con la que el usuario ingrese en este caso 1 dia antes por 
    lo regular*/
    const cortes = await Corte.find({user: req.user.id}).lean();
    res.render('cortes/cortes', {cortes});
});
router.post('/cortes/', async (req, res) => {
    const { fechacorte, vendedor, ventacorte, efectivo,vaucher, sumavalores, diferencia} = req.body;
    const errors = [];
    if (!efectivo) {
        errors.push({text: 'Ingrese el efectivo'});
    }//solo eh echo una validacion de dats en el formulario
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('/cortes/cortes', {
            errors,
            vendedor,
            ventaticket
        });
    }else{
        const newCorte = new Corte({fechacorte, vendedor, ventacorte, efectivo, vaucher, sumavalores, diferencia});
        newCorte.user = req.user.id;
        newCorte.sucursal = req.user.sucursal;
        await newCorte.save();
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Se ingresaron con exito los valores.');
        res.redirect('/cortes/');
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

este es mi Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const CorteSchema = new Schema({
    
    fechacorte: { type: Number, required: true },
    vendedor: { type: String, required: true },
    sucursal: { type: String},
    user: { type: String},
    ventacorte: { type: Number, required: true },
    efectivo: { type: Number, required: true },
    vales: { type: Number, required: true },
    vaucher: { type: Number, required: true },
    sumavalores: { type: Number, required: true },
    diferencia: { type: Number, required: true }
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Corte', CorteSchema);
```

el passport luce algo asi

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/Users');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'usuario'
}, async (usuario, password, done) => {
    const user =  await User.findOne({usuario: usuario});
    if(!user){
        console.log(user);
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Usuario no encontrado.'});
    }else{
        const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
        if (match) {
            return done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(null, false, {message: 'La contraseña es incorrecta'});
        }
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

esta es la apariencia, omiti otros inputs y valores para reducir el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me puedan ayudar, habia creado esto en PHP, AJAX, MYSQL pero me quiero empezar a aprender estoo nuevo e ir aprendiendo mas y mas. gracias

Comment: hola @eivansweb, tu problema esta en esta linea `const cortes = await Corte.find({user: req.user.id}).lean();` ???

Comment: hola @planta4, bueno aqui lo busco a través del id del usuario que ingreso, lo que no puedo encontrar es como muestro los registros ingresados, ejemplo cada que ingresan un nuevo corte se ingresan de un día antes, los de ayer se ingresaron hoy pero en ocasiones tienen que ingresar de días pasados, y el total de registros pueden ser de 2 o hasta 4 registros (vendedores) dependiendo la sucursal. lo que busco es que se muestren es que si ingreso los valores de un vendedor, y luego otro estos se este mostrando pero solo de la misma fecha que estoy ingresando en este día